# Can I change the error message thrown for duplicate key in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, constraints

I have a stored procedure which basically inserts into a table. When a primary key is duplicated, it throws

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint
```

error which I catch in my code and display in my UI.

Is there anyway I can modify this error content to something customized? I know I can use trigger and `RAISE` a customized message. I just want to know if there is an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a function that inserts the row. If the table is called `mytab`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_mytab(p_row mytab) RETURNS void
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   INSERT INTO mytab SELECT (p_row).*;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN unique_violation THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'don''t tickle me';
END;$$;
```

I don't think there is a fundamentally different way.

Answer (score 0):

I have an entire function that executes a certain insert query. Similar to Lauren, I have a statement at the end of the function

```
         ...
         EXCEPTION 
               WHEN unique_violation then 
                  raise exception 'Value already exists in table';
```

Sadly I couldnt find the mapping of the errors to their names (*duplicate key value violates unique constraint* => `unique_violation`) clearly in the documentation...

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30148364)